# Displaying asterisk depending on the number entered

Tags: java

What is the code for making a simple program that displays asterisk depending on the number entered by the user. I want it to go like this

```
Enter 1st Integer:2
Enter 2nd Integer:3
Enter 3rd Integer:4
Enter 4th Integer:5
```

and this would be the result

```
1st Integer:**
2nd Integer:***
3rd Integer:****
4th Integer:*****
```

Simple as it is, I'm having problems regarding this code, I just need the loop for this.

Comment: What problems are you having with _the code_?  Maybe if you could show us _the code_, we might be able to help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem in an unwritten code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int inputNumber = 2;
StringBuilder asteriskBuilder = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < inputNumber; ++i) {
    asteriskBuilder.append("*");
}

//  1st Integer:**
System.out.println("1st Integer:" + asteriskBuilder);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `StringBuilder`

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < inputNumber; ++i) { 
    builder.append("*");
}
System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

if your input number can be big, `StringBuilder` is better solution for you

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 for(int i=1;i<=4;i++)
{
System.out.print(i+"st Integer:");
int input=sc.nextInt();     
System.out.print(i+"st Integer:");
for(int j=0;j<input;j++)
 {
 System.out.print("*");
 }
  System.out.print("\n");
}  
}
catch(Exception e)
{
}
```